# How can I set the default file extension seen in a Windows "Open" box?

Tags: excel, ms-office, file-extension

I use a program called Spec2xlS together with Excel 2013. When I import files to Excel using this program plug-in, the "Open" explorer always has the first alphabetical file extension selected in view, which I never use. It is annoying to always need to change it, especially if I pull up 50 files in a day. Is there any way I can change this default selection to the file type I actually need?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in Windows 8.1, search for "default programs" on the Start screen and click or tap "Default Programs."